# disable the cdrom in Ubuntu 11.10 OS

Tags: 11.10, cd-drive

Can anyone help me how to disable the cdrom in Ubuntu 11.10 OS level.

I tried searching google but I could not find any solution.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/152434/how-to-disable-cd-rom-and-usb-for-normal-users-in-linux

Answer (score 4):

From: [Managing Ubuntu Linux Users and Groups](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Ubuntu_Linux_Users_and_Groups)

To remove a user [eg. john] from membership of a group [eg. accounts] use:

```
sudo deluser john accounts
```

And, to undo:

```
sudo adduser john accounts
```

So to match example (in other answer):

```
sudo deluser tachyons cdrom
sudo adduser tachyons cdrom    [to undo]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Do it in your risk

Take a backup of `/etc/group`

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type `gksudo gedit /etc/group`

Remove the users from cdrom(in this screenshot tachyons is the user name)

[image]

save the file and restart your pc

Comment: your answer is incomplete. plz complete it by writing how to remove users from the cdrom option...

Comment: @Ashu feel free to edit :)

Comment: Added command-line alternative (potentially safer), as separate answer.

Comment: I tried all these things but still normal users are able to access the cdrom

Comment: I tried all these things but still normal users are able to access the cdrom

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of /etc/group