# Permanently disable CD drive

Tags: 12.04, hardware, power-management, drive, optical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disable the cdrom in Ubuntu 11.10 OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135327/disable-the-cdrom-in-ubuntu-11-10-os)

I have no use for a CD drive, ever. Yet it exists, consumes power, opens inadvertently when in its case or in my bed and makes noise whenever computer sleeps, wakes, shuts down or boots.

I would like to shut it out of existence. This will also be true if my next laptop has one too. But in this particular case I don't have the password to access the BIOS (hope it's not required).

`udisks --show-info /dev/sr0` shows

```
drive:
    vendor:                    HL-DT-ST
    model:                     HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T50L
    revision:                  SC04
    serial:                    MKS92IH3934
    WWN:                       
    detachable:                0
    can spindown:              0
    rotational media:          Yes, unknown rate
    write-cache:               unknown
    ejectable:                 1
    adapter:                   /org/freedesktop/UDisks/adapters/0000_3a00_3a1f_2e2
```

I think `detachable: 0` indicates what I want is not possible but I feel like I'm probably not the only one to find a CD drive useless and annoying. So maybe someone has an idea on how to do this.

I was about to test playing with files in `/sys/bus/scsi/devices/1:0:0:0/block/sr0/power` but I'd like to avoid messing with stuff I can't really handle and that could make it unmountable but still annoying or worse.

Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: So unplug it?..

Comment: It should be a solution common to Ubuntu/Linux, not any particular hardware, maybe I have a laptop that's really hard to open like a mac or some other stupid computer...

Comment: Note that while you aren't actively using it, it draws virtually zero power, and the only way to eliminate that trickle is to unplug it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following from this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135327/disable-the-cdrom-in-ubuntu-11-10-os)

Its a little risky but it works.

Backup the file /etc/group

press ctrl+alt+t and type gksudo gedit /etc/group

Remove the users from cdrom(in this screenshot tachyons is the user name)

[image: Image from previous mentioned question]

save the file and restart your pc

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll look into that today, but from the looks of it, that will not disable it completely.