# How do disable the CD-ROM for all users?

Tags: mount, permissions, udev, cd-drive, udisks

I want to disable CDROM/CDRW/DVDROM/DVDRW for everyone in Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop 64-bit edition.

I have tried following but not worked:

1. Removed user from `/etc/group`, as following: `cdrom:x:24:`

   as defined at [Permanently disable CD drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222671/permanently-disable-cd-drive?lq=1)
2. Defined rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/71-cdrom-block.rules` and `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-cdrom-block.rules` as follows:

   ```
   ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM}="1", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0", ENV{UDISKS_SYSTEM_INTERNAL}="1",         ENV{UDISKS_AUTOMOUNT_HINT}="never"
   ```

   as defined at https://superuser.com/questions/693155/disable-device-node-using-udev-dev-sr0

But still I am able mount the CD-ROM. Kindly help how to disable it for everyone.

Comment: visit this 
        
http://askubuntu.com/questions/135327/disable-the-cdrom-in-ubuntu-11-10-os

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this to change the permissions of the drive to root only

```
sudo chmod 700 /media/path/to/your/DVDRom
```

Your mount point is in /media/DVDdrivenamehere

This will make it requier root password and

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/path/to/your/DVDRom
```

Will allow full accsess againg

To disable DVD auto-play open system settings and go to details

On the left choose removable media, you can easily set auto-play parameters. from here

Comment: I am getting error while running#  "sudo fstab nouser" command
Error : "sudo: fstab: command not found"
Which package is needed to install fstab command in 14.04.1 ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install fstab, it should be installed.

Comment: If that does not work sudo chmod +x /etc/fstab.d and try again

Comment: Still fstab command not worked.  <br/># sudo chmod +x /etc/fstab.d
# sudo fstab nouser
sudo: fstab: command not found
# ls -l /etc/fstab.d
total 0
# cd /etc/fstab.d/
:/etc/fstab.d# ls
:/etc/fstab.d# ls -l
total 0

Comment: New answer for you

Comment: Now user is not able to mount CDrom but getting display error "Unable to open a folder for....No application is registred as handling this file".    Can be it done silently.

Comment: I dont know what you meen silently you said you wanted it disabled for ALL user only root can mount the drive.

Comment: Actually doing chmod 700 to /mount folder block others users to mount cdrom but whenever anyone insert cdrom Ubuntu OS try to automount the media and dues to rights issue it gives message to user. How can I disable automount facility also.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I will update myanswer